# Does anyone know how to test components in compose without using the modifier to set the testTag?

Tags: android, kotlin, google-maps, automated-tests, android-jetpack-compose

I'm working with the google maps api and google maps has some components to be set, but these components don't have a modifier, only a tag field in the constructor, does anyone know how I can get this tag to perform tests?

```
 Polyline(
            points = it,
            color = Color.Blue,
            tag = MAP_ROUTE_TAG
        )
```

Test

```
composeTestRule.onNodeWithTag(MAP_ROUTE_TAG).assertIsDisplayed()
```

Error

```
Failed to perform isDisplayed check.
Reason: Expected exactly '1' node but could not find any node that satisfies: (TestTag = 'map_route_tag')
```

I would like to have access to this tag for testing.

Answer (score 0):

Tag is not TestTag.
If u want to use TestTag, try to add modifier =

```
Modifier.testTag("YourAwesomeTestTagName")
```

go to Polyline() and add this:

```
modifier: Modifier = Modifier
```

And then you should be able to do what you want to do:

```
Polyline(
        points = it,
        color = Color.Blue,
        tag = MAP_ROUTE_TAG,
        modifier = Modifier.testTag("YourAwesomeTestTagName")
    )
```

I hope it helps.